# Volume in Geometry

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

A cylinder has a radius of $2$ and a height of $9$. It is $1/3$ filled with water. What is the volume of the water?

Can someone explain how to solve this! This is what I did:
$V=\pi r^2h$, $V=36\pi$

Is it $36-2/3=24$
or $36-1/3=12$?

Answer (score 5):

The total volume is, as you calculated, $36\pi$. But you have $1/3$ filled, that is $36\pi \cdot \frac{1}{3}=12\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the height of the cylinder is stationary, and it is filled $1/3$ with water, we have:

$$V = \pi(2)^2(9/3) = \pi(4)(3) = 12\pi \text{ units}^3$$